# Problems in extracting data from a text-based output using PowerShell 5.0

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a text-based output (similiar to XML), which looks like the following:

```
<result type="hidden" name="__SYSTEMSTATE" id="__SYSTEMSTATE" value="avSqTjf3nt5Kbo7FI7zE4N3x9P+DJ7qCesGCC47Gh4W60NRdNbR5NA/zRAUvBWIL9knVKQMEEv4CcQnMTjJL6Mc52JToyX0QX6OUk/PbtI7Xxt6FUe66eVOtbp3gm6yhTr50IQ9o5DF0C
HXQvZnWrUrfUHfiO4vIzrg7bPl7VWvlMBxf04/Qid1H0cKu3oIURQvcvLoHYI84P6zcHCoQZf1o0Nc4ZMWUwie7aPPKNI7WgqJbyMLSq3D04blL/lrycV67y8fB/xNr8cYGn+RTzgzcybMAJ1JVtUrQsb/+iWtO5WBTVfPlnrCsDztBaHW4fb069zvFGzNAj0kzlig5qy37qf
28SoGV75RWvW5hNbzvkFzFRQrBj6KdvbxV5XVE3A0F8MlLB5t6DFIErfj/j0gZ+9dMGad9EeyjvYsW2VXGlsAtsgTEKX4SqYNnxeEBXdPqzDXhGmzN/mCwXCYnFzcrfdb7Nxl/2+BgI39lRiCTNJiQszx0q6yHQyEURIccj5+PEJCgniUFXBk2V/uUPilpwQAgbL6ZECLnByf
eUUf+wrMEZk30A2YQ3ViBQ3wlLy/iHNyP0N2rZtNhXh7F7K672gQjWBXEJOW8V9gygs3+k0LdrX95wdRT45F6Dit9V9RsgwuLisPaRWK/gyczeP3+NApvz7h0e05i1ePqZ8nU5G+YszwUYB8zF2wJGY8h+Hl4ywEklq6r45AfRKsflSXHJ0yrU3q1JIIcFK0cvsOhOP0x6450
32iIjm6TTW6mrG2MC3GGUaIKJ0UH4wctmwLKvaEOx1ATKyVXj7MH9WcDPbs8RuieTaH8sZ4OkwVn1s2XlV3C1URLsWZMV6MaokvHzu8CloCecZNzYJj2JGDMztuS0zA7UhXlHdoHMx8EFbo62jiEbI7TUTlEGDoDpb/v0+++k/fhvImotfMZbGApO2mcL3UWUSP5JN3a6Jb9S
LLSe1PMhi0V+0BShNEHQyfcjvV+IMdLzs0CSeRxZzCONz8eyBgrhS0e8DOrfdxQ65ja2mORD+9daepw3E5aNN8kgILEYnP0axA+8a02K+qPrnYYzrIdsSxrQWQY69qMR2Ii+WN99v9kRrHq6D0mEF94NA4bofmTtWiS2S0DCSnQeGzQy0gk8VrTBOklFOMddaV3o4bE1L3ICK
xh6zDfpx0XrIJJLUxti8nI8RR5gVXNlqjSZSjTcHRTP6CtVv66xH+qGDI78XS7ksuksce3XnpOUxtpitYmrdpYfc1Bxm1QJDRBJHj0Exi3HreYAeBl+mAOyoOmbHgbK+oEULLFalklYNuNQVqeyny5n9Sl2f/f4CoNyCvd6eGOzBcCga6/S+1M0en3HlXze9xOBMRJGIiWUyw
PJOFlyOfuViNJphiVo5lllAxekF/xC8t4PODVd8uKClY2nLkl3wD6mbwHminD4Bup5ZJv9YUGddjHuWuL5RV8rSnWxx3tQreZxSkJ6rnhL2IrVmlBd9AC1ycZazsdmslO8yOBr79thetnUOw=" />
<result type="hidden" name="__SYSTEMSTATEGENERATOR" id="__SYSTEMSTATEGENERATOR" value="BFF85B2E" />
<result type="hidden" name="__STATUSVALIDATION" id="__STATUSVALIDATION" value="os7HBRwF1z3X7ws/k4J+Ei9L/Lu4GoRMDXaKkFB0T/bexhneBH+0Wi0R+k+7VgZw0nue5Dsp92/3rwMnnpdEl+oUs3RaqRS2v1+Ej4h5WFZyRamvboEnMGNZMySNTIve9
LAQW5KBLCw3aQWmxXZidjSf5NR7r/T+sEJYJG9BpRc=" />
<result type="password" style="display:none"/>
<result name="UserName" type="text" id="Login1_UserName" class="control" />
<result name="Password" type="password" id="Login1_Password" class="control" />
<result type="submit" name="LoginButton" value="Anmelden" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("LoginButton", "", true, "$Login1", "", false, false))" id="Login1_LoginButton" class="btn btn-danger" />
```

I want to extract `result name` and `value` and parse it in array using PowerShell 5.0, but I am not able to do so as i.e. `Where-Object` or `Split` did not give me a clue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know that it was not working but do you have an example of actual code you were trying to use. This reads like a code writing request and your question can go a lot farther if effort is _shown_. What about the lines that have name and no value? Do you need those? It also help for these question for you to show your expected output.

Comment: What have you tried? "Something or other did not give me a clue" doesn't tell us anything. We need to see the actual code you tried. What result did you expect? What was the result you actually got? Did you receive an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: For some unknown reason nearly all of my projects, which were lying on a share, had been deleted due to a hardware crash. During the last 30 minutes I tried to restore them, but unfortunately the one we are talking about here is not among them :-(. Sorry in not being able to answer your valid points :-(.

Comment: case closed then, you don't need to know the answer to this question

Comment: interesting as my original problem still exists... I only am not able to provide sample code here unfortunately (as said)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$template=@"
{Row*:name="{name:_Test1}"}
"@

Get-Content "C:\temp\test3.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | %{$_.Row.name}
```